# RStudio 1.4 - libssl.so.1.0.0

Tags: ubuntu, libraries, rstudio-server

I am trying to install RStudio on Ubuntu 20.04. However, when I try to run Rstudio using the application icon it does not launch. When I try to use the command line to run rstudio it returns the error `**rstudio: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`**. Can anyone help on how to sort this issue.

I am using R4.0 and Rstudio 1.4 (daily release). The version 1.2.5 colapses when I click in any menu icon.

Please, help!

Answer (score 6):

I got an answer by executing the following statements in the command line:
`wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.3_amd64.deb`

and then

```
dpkg -i ./libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.3_amd64.deb
```

It is now working perfectly.

Thanks,

Comment: Just tried this,  got a 404 .   bummer

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 20.04, it's quite easy to miss the correct Rstudio 1.4 download, which is further down the downloads page (look for "Install for Debian 10 / Ubuntu 18 / Ubuntu 20").

This works perfectly without having to install the old, insecure libssl1.0, which is now libssl1.1 on my systems on Ubuntu 20.04